# WA in IITKWPCO SPOJ

Tags: c

This is a question from `SPOJ`

Little Feluda likes to play very much. As you know he only plays with numbers. So he is given n numbers. Now tries to group the numbers into disjoint collections each containing two numbers. He can form the collection containing two numbers iff small number in the collection is exactly half of large number.

Given n numbers, Find out how many maximum number of collections he can form ?

Input

T: number of test cases. (1 <= T <= 100).

For each test case:

First line will contain n :  (1 <= n <= 100)

Then next line will contain n numbers single space seperated. Range of each number will be between 1 and 10^6.

Output

For each test case, output maximum number of collections that can be formed.

Example

> Input:
>
> 2
>
> 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 3
>
> 1 2 4
>
> Output:
>
> 1
>
> 1

my code::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    
    while (t--) {
            int n, i, j;
            scanf("%d", &n);
            long int arr[n], mini, maxi;
            char str[105];
            
            for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
                    str[i] = '0';
                    scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
            }
      
            for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
                    for (j = 0;j < n;j++) {
                            mini = fmin(arr[i], arr[j]);
                            maxi = fmax(arr[i], arr[j]);
                            if ((maxi == 2 * mini) && (str[i] == '0' && str[j] == '0')) {
                                    str[i] = str[j] = '1';
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
           
            long int cnt = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
                    if (str[i] == '1') {
                            cnt++;
                    }
            }
            
            printf("%ld\n", cnt / 2);
            
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

can someone plz point out where i am going wrong or any corner test case that i am missing??

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i am getting correct output for all the test cases i tried but still on SPOJ it evaluates to WRONG ANSWER.I created a character array and initialized it to all '0' and if lower number is half of higher number then i initialize that position with '1'.after that i will get even number of 1's in "str".so i just divided count by 2 to get the number of pairs that was asked in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flaw in your logic.

Consider the case where the input array is {2,4,1,8}

The answer for this should be 2, since the collections {1,2} and {4,8} can be formed. However, your code will output 1 for this case (it will pair 2 with 4, and be able to create only one collection).

I have solved this problem by sorting the array, then for each element, check whether two times that element exists or not. If yes, mark it as used and increment the count of collections.

(pseudo-code):

```
sort(array)
count = 0;
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
  if(used[i]) continue; //used elements should not be re-considered
  for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
     if(array[j]==2*array[i] && !used[j]){
        used[j] = true;.
        count++;
     }
  }
}
```

The variable *count* will now have the maximum possible number of collections.

Note that searching for 2*array[i] in the array can also be implemented by binary search, but that would be unnecessary since the array is really small (size <=100)

Here's my  [C++ code](https://github.com/akhiluanandh/SPOJ/blob/master/IITKWPCO.cpp)   for the problem. ( I have used the c++ standard library for sorting, you may use any sorting algorithm of your choice ).

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check out this easy solution: 
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t>0)
    {
        t=t-1;
        int num=0;
        long long int n[10001];
        int count=0;
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(int k=0;k<num;k++)
        scanf("%lld",&n[k]);
        sort(n,n+num);
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            if(n[i]==-1)continue;
            for(int j=i+1;j<num;j++)
            {
                if(n[j]==n[i]*2 &&n[i]!=-1 &&n[j]!=-1 )
                {
                    count=count+1;
                    n[i]=-1;
                    n[j]=-1;
                    break;
                    }


                }

            }

        printf("%d\n",count);

        }




//  getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: This question can easily be done by the bruteforce as you know .

Comment: First I sort the array in increasing order , if i pick the first element and check using the inner for loop that which element satisifes the criteria like if i choose the ith element from the outer loop and check that where a[j]=2*a[i];where the jth element is pick from inner loop,now increase the count by "1" and just mark this element -1 like a[i]=-1 and a[j]=-1    beacuse it can not used further.Next time if the status a[i]==-1 just continue  because somewhere it is already used  to make set. You can also use qsort which takes nlogn time to sort the array.If you still in doubt let me know.